# How to pause and resume the file upload in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I have tried to upload the file using below code

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="Files" id="file1" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>      
        <progress id="progressBar" class='progressbar' value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;height:5px"></progress>
      <h3 id="status"></h3>
      <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
```

Below is my script section

```
function uploadFile() {
  var files =  document.getElementById("file1") .files[0] ;
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("Files", files);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", **myserverpathhere**);
  ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

While the upload is inprogress, I like to pause the file uploading and Need to resume the paused file.

How can i achieve it using javascript ?

Comment: you should try Resumable.js . https://tus.io/demo.html

Comment: Hi @imanshu15,
Is resumable.js is third party plugin ?

Comment: Yes, It’s a JavaScript library providing multiple simultaneous, stable and resumable uploads via the HTML5 File API.

Comment: Hi, Is any other ways available to achieve my requirement ?

Comment: You can use local storage as per this [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/19/supporting-resumable-file-uploads-using-html5/) , Note that this would be fine if the file not really that large.